# How to passed multiple selected list into variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to passed my selected list in variable. Like this but it prints me a `undefined` value.

```
function showUserOptions(a)
{
    var b = console.log(a[a.selectedIndex].value);
    alert (b);
}
```

I can get the value using `console.log` but I want the user click the selected list the value inside in variable will changed.

Form:

```
<div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "to" class = "control-label">To:</label>
            <select onChange = "showUserOptions(this)" name = "to" class = "form-control" multiple>

            @foreach ($result as $list)
                <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function getDocuments()
{
    $result = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();

    return view ('document.create')->with('result', $result);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `onChange`. Use the `on()` event handler instead

Comment: I just want to passed the selected list in variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide a id to your drop down, and its name will be an array so  that it can hold multiple values like:

```
    <select name="myDropDown[]" id="myDropDown" class= "form-control" multiple>

        @foreach ($result as $list)
            <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>

 $('#myDropDown').change(function(){
        var selectedVal = $(this).val();    
     // it will return the selected values in an array
 });
```

Try this, it work.

Comment: Hey this works!! Why I need to put array inside my `name`? Is it possible that I passed that value in the variable and insert this into database?

Comment: 1. Array is necessary because you can select multiple values from multi select drop down and a single variable is not able to hold multiple value in it.
2. Yes you can use selectedVal in ajax call and save the values in database.

Enjoy :)

Comment: I see. In your example I'm able to get this value in array. You're a life saver! Can I insert this without using ajax call? Because I still don't have any experience using ajax. :)

Comment: Try this:

$.ajax({
 url  : 'save_data.php',
 method  : 'post',
 data  : 
 {
  var_name : value,
  var_name : value
 },
 success : function(response)
 {
  // response contain the response from save_data.php
 }
})